# How can I disable the animations in an NSCollectionView

Tags: cocoa, animation

I would like to turn off the 'shuffle' animations that happen when you resize an NSCollectionView. Is this possible?

Comment: Any progress on this one? Have the same problem and do not want private APIs.

Answer (score 5):

This works, but it's setting a private instance variable so it may no be ok in the Mac App Store.

```
[collectionView setValue:@(0) forKey:@"_animationDuration"];
```

Answer (score 3):

kainjow is correct. adding this:

```
- (id) animationForKey:(NSString *) key
{
    return nil;
}
```

to the prototype view subclass (not the collection view!) disables animations

Answer (score 2):

For 10.6, I was able to disable the animation by subclassing NSView, overriding animationForKey: and returning nil. Then make sure you use that view for the prototype's view.

Comment: Isn't animationForKey: on CALayer, not NSView?

Comment: It's part of the NSAnimatablePropertyContainer protocol which NSView conforms to.

Comment: animationForKey does not get called on my class subclass of NSCollectionView.

Comment: I wasn't able to get this technique to work either, so a longer explanation or a sample would be helpful. For now I am changing the private ivar as suggested by Padraig.

Answer (score 2):

To disable all the collection view's animations in Swift, do this just before the something animatable happens:

```
NSAnimationContext.current.duration = 0
```

Comment: genius solution

Answer (score 0):

I was only able to get this to work if I did the following:

1) Subclass the view that the NSCollectionViewItem used as its view. That subclassed view required a CALayer and I set the view subclass as the delegate of the CALayer.

2) Implement the CALayer delegate method so no animation actions should occur:

```
override func actionForLayer(layer: CALayer, forKey event: String) -> CAAction? {
        return NSNull()
}
```

3) Finally, in the NSCollectionView data source method:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: NSCollectionView, itemForRepresentedObjectAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> NSCollectionViewItem {

    // get a new collection view item
    ....

    // disable animations
    CATransaction.begin()
    CATransaction.setDisableActions(true)

    // populate your cell
    ....

    CATransaction.commit()    
}
```